# How can I close / dismiss Bootstrap Popover when clicking the popover trigger element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, popover

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kAYyR/

**Screenshot:**

[image: screenshot]

Here's what works:

1. Open popover on button click
2. Close popover on click outside popover
3. Close popover on click of `.close` button

BUT...  I cannot get the popover to close when you click the original button again.  Instead the popover flashes off and on again.

**Duplicate it yourself [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kAYyR/).**

How can I accomplish this?

**HTML:**

```
<button id="popoverId" class="popoverThis btn btn-large btn-danger">Click to toggle popover</button>
<div id="popoverContent" class="hide">This <em>rich</em> <pre>html</pre> content goes inside popover</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#popoverId').popover({
    html: true,
    title: "Popover Title",
    content: function () {
        return $('#popoverContent').html();
    }
});


var isVisible = false;
var clickedAway = false;

$('.popoverThis').popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'manual'
}).click(function (e) {
    $(this).popover('show');
    $('.popover-content').append('<a class="close" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 6px;">&times;</a>');
    clickedAway = false
    isVisible = true
    e.preventDefault()
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (isVisible & clickedAway) {
        $('.popoverThis').popover('hide')
        isVisible = clickedAway = false
    } else {
        clickedAway = true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Do you want work like this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/kAYyR/3/

```
$('#popoverId').popover({
    html: true,
    title: 'Popover Title<a class="close" href="#");">&times;</a>',
    content: $('#popoverContent').html(),
});

$('#popoverId').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (($('.popover').has(e.target).length == 0) || $(e.target).is('.close')) {
        $('#popoverId').popover('hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: No.  I can't have the popover dismiss on any click anywhere.  The popover should just dismiss on (1) .close, (2) outside the .popover, (3) on original button.  You should be able to freely click on the popover as much as you want without it dismissing.

Comment: What mean of outside popover and on original button?

Comment: Just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kAYyR/  Except when the red button is clicked again it dismisses the popover.

Comment: Updated: now dismiss on, click outside of popover or click close button

Comment: Nice.  That works... EXCEPT, now I can only have one popover per page (unless I add a stopPropagation for each popover).  Why won't it work with just classes?

Comment: Nevermind, this works perfectly with multiple buttons.  See updated jsfiddle to see how changing some ids to classes works: http://jsfiddle.net/kAYyR/4/

Comment: @Ryan do you know any way to make the JavaScript code more inline with DRY by using only a single `$('#popoverBtnN').popover({` function and perhaps adding additional HTML code if needed?

Comment: @Ryan Where is the class .popover ? I don't understand this code

Answer (score 10):

I use this:

```
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html: true, container: 'body'});

    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').not(this).popover('hide');
        $(this).popover('toggle');
    });

    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).parent().find('[data-toggle="popover"]').length > 0) {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

it can simply done by using this code

```
<div id='content'>something here</div>
 $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            return $('#content').html();
        }
    }).click(function (e) {
        $('[data-toggle=popover]').not(this).popover('hide');
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

This simple code will hide all popovers on the page
$('.popover').popover('hide');