# How to hide the popovers when click outside of popovers

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Please refer to this demo, how to hide popovers when clicking anywhere outside of popovers. Now we could hide it by clicking the links, but we want to hide it by clicking anywhere outside of popovers. Please kindly help me, thanks a lot.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id="popover1" data-original-title="<b>testing</b>" data-placement="bottom">Click</a>

    <div id="popover_content_wrapper1" style="display: none">
        <a href="#" id="popover2" data-original-title="<b>testing again</b>" data-placement="bottom">Click again</a>
    </div>

    <div id="popover_content_wrapper2" style="display: none">
        <b>Hello world</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#popover1').popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'manual',
    content: function() {
        return $('#popover_content_wrapper1').html();
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '#popover1', function() {
    $(this).popover('toggle');
    $('#popover2').popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'manual',
    content: function() {
        return $('#popover_content_wrapper2').html();
    }
});
});

$(document).on('click', '#popover2', function() {
    $(this).popover('toggle');
});
```

Please try this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kg7nyo6e/1/

Comment: maybe you can use this answer as a reference http://stackoverflow.com/a/15945492/7675768